# Try sending sms again when for some reason is not sent the first time

Tags: java, android

I am a newcomer to androi. My problem is the following I have a code that sends text messages all right but I would like to be able to do that when the sending of the message fails automatically try to send it again about 3 times after that if it is not sent since it does nothing.
Greetings I hope you can help me I had a good time with this problem.

Here I leave the code.

```
public class Principal extends Activity {

EditText txtPhone;
EditText txtMsg;
Button btnSend;
TextView msj;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    txtPhone = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPhone ));
    txtMsg = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMsg ));
    btnSend = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend ));
    msj = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmsj));

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);

                    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

                        @Override
                        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                            switch (getResultCode()){

                                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                    msj.setText("SMS SENT");

                                    break;
                                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                                    msj.setText("I can not send SMS");

                                    break;
                                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                                    msj.setText("service not available");

                                    break;
                                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                                    msj.setText("PDU (Protocol Data Unit) es NULL");

                                    break;
                                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                                    msj.setText("turn on the radio");
                                               break;

                            }
                        }
                    }, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));

                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if( txtPhone.getText().toString().length()> 0 &&
                            txtMsg.getText().toString().length()>0 )
                    {
                        sms.sendTextMessage( txtPhone.getText().toString() , null, txtMsg.getText().toString() , sentIntent, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can not send, data is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OK sorry. Just like the app with that code I send normal text messages I add a number and the message. It is sent without any problem but when I do not have a balance or there is a problem with the network it appears that it is not sent until all is well. I would like that when that happens that the same app tries to send the sms 3 times after those attempts if the sending fails that it does not do anything else. I hope I have explained thanks for replying.